# array sorting error in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 4 values in my NSDictionary below which are 1000,640,80 and 0
It sorts the non-zero values correctly but it always gives 0 as greater than all the other values like (descending): 0,1000,640,80 Here's the code:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[self model] stateFromDocumentNamed:@"state"];
    NSArray *values=[dict allValues];
    NSMutableArray *mutvalues = [(NSArray*)values mutableCopy];
    [mutvalues sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    values=[[values reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
    NSLog(@"%@",mutvalues);
```

Comment: 0 comes before 1.  0 < 1 < 6 < 8.  You would get the same result if you used 0, 1, 6, 8 rather than 1000, 640, and 80.  In which case they'd be in order.

Comment: are your values NSStrings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you are comparing strings which contain numbers. To have the sort work as you expect with the numbers you will want to use the `NSNumericSearch` option (in the method `compare:options:`, probably used with `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`).

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because the objects in your NSMutableDictionary are strings instead of numbers. Possible solutions:

- You would need to convert all objects to numbers
- Use a different selector to sort
- sort using a block, using `sortedArrayUsingComparator`
- EDIT: sort using method proposed in Wain's answer